# Is it possible to never run vacuum full in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, locking, vacuum

Since a `VACUUM FULL` locks tables, it is unacceptable for us in our production environment.

Is it possible to only run `VACUUM` and never `VACUUM FULL` on a production system?

Does `VACUUM` make space reusable for new `INSERT`s?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to understand the differences between

- `VACUUM`
- `VACUUM ANALYZE`
- `VACUUM FULL`,

a basic understanding of PostgreSQL's architecture is required.

From [several9s](https://severalnines.com/blog/overview-vacuum-processing-postgresql/)<sup>1</sup> we are told that:

> - PostgreSQL does not use IN-PLACE update mechanism, so as per the way DELETE and UPDATE command is designed,
>
>   - Whenever DELETE operations are performed, it marks the existing tuple as DEAD instead of physically removing those tuples.
>   - Similarly, whenever UPDATE operation is performed, it marks the corresponding existing tuple as DEAD and inserts a new tuple (i.e.
>     UPDATE operation = DELETE + INSERT).

This leads to what is called "bloat" - i.e. the table will become bigger, **even if** the number of records remains the same because of these dead tuples.

From [EnterpriseDB](https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/postgresql-vacuum-and-analyze-best-practice-tips)<sup>2</sup>, we have:

> - When a vacuum process runs, the space occupied by these dead tuples is marked reusable by other tuples.

This is analgous to deleting a file in the file system - the space is merely marked as reusable and nothing is actually deleted. This doesn't matter - the important thing to note is that the space taken by the row becomes **available** again to the PostgreSQL server for that table!

The **key difference** between `VACUUM` and `VACUUM FULL` is that with a `VACUUM FULL`, the freed up space **also** becomes available to the OS! This might be of use if one wishes to perform a backup and one is running low on disk space. From [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56727/34007):

> - Vacuum full takes out an exclusive lock and rebuilds the table so that it has no empty blocks (we'll pretend fill factor is 100% for
>   now).

So, `VACUUM FULL` is analgous to defragging a disk file (consider a disk file ≡ PostgreSQL table), from [Percona](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/02/04/pg_repack-rebuild-postgresql-database-objects-online/)<sup>3</sup> we have:

> VACUUM FULL is the default option available with a PostgreSQL installation that allows us to **REBUILD** a table. [Emphasis mine]

However, this rebuild does, require an [Access Exclusive Lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html), which as the manual points out:

> - ACCESS EXCLUSIVE
>
>   Conflicts with locks of all modes (ACCESS SHARE, ROW SHARE, ROW EXCLUSIVE, SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE, SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE,
>   EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE). This mode guarantees that the
>   **holder is the only transaction accessing the table in any way**. [Emphasis mine]

Obviously, and as you point out, a complete rewrite of the table isn't great for production. The [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-vacuum.html) even says:

> - Usually this should only be used when a significant amount of space needs to be reclaimed from within the table.

So, to answer your 2 questions:

### Q. 1)

> does the vacuum make the space reuseable for the new insert?

Yes, it does, but **even more importantly**, it **doesn't** take an Access Exclusive lock. From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html), we find that:

> Autovacuum workers generally don't block other processes.

[`Autovacuum`](https://matam-kirankumar.medium.com/auto-vacuum-in-postgresql-f78b4b861d6b) is a `VACUUM` without the `FULL` and is normally configured in the `postgresql.conf` file.

`VACUUM` takes a SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE lock.

Again, from the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html):

> This mode protects a table against concurrent schema changes and VACUUM runs.

Or as explained by a knowledgeable PostgreSQL contributor [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/176664/34007):

> Autovacuum does take a lock on the table, but it is a weak lock which does not interfere with normal operations (SELECT, UPDATE,
> DELETE) but will interfere with things like adding indexes, or
> truncating the table.

The EnterpriseDB blog referenced above gives "VACUUM and ANALYZE Best Practice Tips" - personally, I would normally advise an `ANALYZE` after a `VACUUM` to update the table's statistics for the optimizer! This article can also help you with decisions as to **when** you might want to run `VACUUM`.

### Q. 2)

The question as asked in the subject.

> Is it possible never to run vacuum full in PostgreSQL

Yes, it is possible to never run it, especially if disk space isn't a worry. It **may** be worthwhile however, as a complete table rewrite (along with indexes) can have a beneficial impact on query performance - records in physical order can lead to fewer pages requiring scans!

### Conclusion.

This is a complex issue and a complete answer would be impossibly long, but I would urge you to read [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/VACUUM_FULL) - a bit dated but a good overview - (and also the pages [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html), [here](https://pankajconnect.medium.com/vacuum-and-vacuum-full-postgresql-4c9da30a1500), [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/what-is-fillfactor-and-how-does-it-affect-postgresql-performance/) (fill factor) & [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/08/06/basic-understanding-bloat-vacuum-postgresql-mvcc/)).

Of course, you don't want `VACUUM`ing interrupting your production systems at busy times. Deciding on the best strategy is the same as virtually everything else in IT - **`"It depends!"`**.

There are disk space and I/O load parameters to be taken into account and you will have to arrive at a compromise which best suits all of your stakeholders.

<sup>1) several9s is an excellent site for all things PostgreSQL.</sup>
<sup>2) EnterpriseDB is also an excellent site and the largest PostgreSQL company with a large number of core team members and contributors.</sup>
<sup>3) Percona, although previously a MySQL company, now also have a PostgreSQL distribution, and they sponsor the promising [pg_stat_monitor](https://github.com/percona/pg_stat_monitor) extension (see also [here](https://percona.github.io/pg_stat_monitor/REL_1_STABLE/)). They are highly regarded.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> It may be worthwhile however, as a complete table rewrite (along with indexes) can have a beneficial impact on query performance - records in physical order can lead to fewer pages requiring scans!

If you are interested in the above, you may want to have a look at the CLUSTER command.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/199982)

Answer (score -2):

For super users, we can't block vacuum full & only vacuum on the table no going to  make the space reusable, we have to use vacuum full to physically remove the dead tuple.